# How are Vasto Lorde different from the Espada?

Tags: bleach

There are a lot of threads on the internet that have confusing/contradicting answers, but how are Vasto Lorde different from the Espada?

Comment: Vasto lorde are weak ... Nnoitra(when he was 8 in espada ) was sent to recruit vasto lorde but he killed him

Comment: Actually if a hollow was a vasto lorde before they became arrancar would mean they would be an arrancar plus vasto lorde wich would make them stronger than any other arrancar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vasto Lorde are the top of the Hollow species. However, they are Hollow, not Arrancar.

Arrancars are Hollow which, using the power of the Hogyoku, removed the boundry between Hollow and Shinigami, and achieved a greater power, usually by removing their masks and sealing most of their power into a sword.

Espada, are by definition the top ten *Arrancar*. **They may or many not be Vasto Lorde**.

It was heavily implied that of all the Espada, only the top four (Ulquiorra, Halibel, Barragan and Stark) were Vasto Lorde before they became Arrancars (and subsequently Espada).

Comment: i remember seeing grimmjow as a vasto lorde too, maybe gonna comment in the next few days again, as i'm currently rewatching.

Comment: @Vogel612: Grimmjow never made it to the Vasto Lorde class, he was recruited as an Adjuchas.

Comment: The [Arrancar page at Bleach wikia](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Arrancar) indicates that Arrancar existed before Aizen and his Hogyoku, so the Espada are the top ten Arrancar _within Aizen's army_.

Comment: aizen made some arrancar with the Hogyoku, there exist natural arrancar, normaly they are vasto lorde

Answer (score -2):

Hallows have 3 ranks apart from their basic form :
1st rank Gillian also called menos Grande
2nd rank Adjuchas 
3rd rank Vasto Lorde
these hollows keep their hallow forms.

Now Hallows who attained powers like a soul reaper are called Arrancar (which means to rip/tear off) and do not have the hollow defining skull mask and look human like with only a fragment of their mask attached to their head.
Espada are simply the top ten strongest Arrancar in Sousuke Aizen' s army of Arrancar. Hope this was helpful

Comment: This answer covers similar ground to an existing answer.  Unfortunately, you're not adding anything new here.

Answer (score -4):

Vasto Lorde are extremely powerful hollows. Hitsuguya suggested that if Aizen were to get ten Arrancars on Vasto Lorde level, the Soul Society would be doomed. For

> Vasto lorde are weak ... Nnoitra(when he was 8 in espada ) was sent to recruit vasto lorde but he killed him

[user4640](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/how-are-vasto-lorde-different-from-the-espada/37420#comment11054_7515) is mistelling the information. In episode 202, Nnoitra was talking to Nel, who asked him why he destroyed an entire colony of hollows. He said he did it because he was not told not to, as well he was looking for Vasto Lorde. The exact quote is,

> If I could kill them(Hollows) off that easily, then they couldn't be Vasto Lorde.

Espada are extremely powerful Hollows made into Arrancars. Arrancars come from the Hogyoku, where the Vasto Lorde cannot come from being an Arrancar. Arrancars lose the evolutionary step because they are in between Soul reaper and hollows. Only hollows that do not become Arrancars can be become vasto Lordes. However, Vasto Lordes can become Arrancars.

Comment: i have rollbacked your changes because they didn't improve the post. bold facing all the non-quote text hurts readability